# How to get the ID from this function and match it to my other table to get the Product_name (laravel)

Tags: laravel

```
public function viewCustomerOrders(){
    $orders = Order::with('ordersz')->get();

    return view('admin.orders.view_customers_order')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

**my public function code**

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Order extends Model
    {
        public function ordersz(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct','order_id');
        }
        function product() {
            return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
        }
    }
```

**my relation on my Order Model**

Is it possible to do this one?

```
foreach($orders->ordersz as $try){
    $getTheProductIDfromOrdersTabel= $try->product_id;
    matchItTomyProductTableTogetName= Product::where('id',$getTheProductIDfromOrdersTabel)->get();
}
```

Because i have the orders table, and order_products table, and inside it is i have the order_id and product_id, i want to get the product_id from my condition and match it on my products table to display their product_names.

Comment: and pls teach me how to call in on my view file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is a [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. In order to include all the requisite data you'll use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Consider three tables - `orders`, `products`, and `order_product`. The respective models would be defined like:

**Order**

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Product**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
    }
}
```

The pivot table - `order_product` - would be only need two columns: `order_id` and `product_id`.

Now your controller method can be updated as:

```
public function viewCustomerOrders()
{
    return view('admin.orders.view_customers_order')->with([
        'orders' => Order::with('products')->get()
    ]);
}
```

Finally, to display the information in your view file, use `@foreach`:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    Order ID: {{ $order->id }}
    @foreach($order->products as $product)
        Product Name: {{ $product->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'e_grocery.order_product' doesn't exist (SQL: select `products`.*, `order_product`.`order_id` as `pivot_order_id`, `order_product`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id` from `products` inner join `order_product` on `products`.`id` = `order_product`.`product_id` where `order_product`.`order_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20))

Comment: sir its working now , i make a order_product table new one, but pls sir, one more help, can you please explain how this codes works, Thank you so much ,